# Sticky buttons to the side of a website (not moving)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two social media buttons that I'd like to keep to the side and stay there even when scrolling down, tried an `<ul>` but the buttons are in an awkward position on the top as of now.

**Current:**

[image: home]

**Goal:** (taken from another site)

[image: goal]

Button:

```
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-light social-media-button fa fa-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/infinitygroupint/"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-light social-media-button fa fa-instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/infinitygroup.ph/"></a>
      <li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.social-media-button {
    position: absolute;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 2px solid #fff !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}

.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.btn-outline-light {
    color: #f8f9fa;
    border-color: #f8f9fa;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

What should I add in my css to keep the buttons to the side? Again it's to the side and it stays on the same position when I scroll down.

Comment: You already appear to have them absolutely positioned.  You now need to tell them where be.  Using `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right`.

Comment: it still scrolls alongside the page though, id like it to just stick on one place

Comment: Sorry, I meant you need to use `position: fixed`, not `absolute`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of position absolute, you need to add position fixed and then give top and right.
as shown in eg.

```
.social-media-button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

You need to set `position fixed` instead of `absolute` to parent div `ul`:

and set `top` `left` `right` `bottom` as per your requirement.

```css
.container {
  height: 900px;
  /*temp height for demo*/
}

.container ul {
  position: fixed;
}

.container ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.social-media-button {
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 2px solid #fff !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
}

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.btn-outline-light {
  color: #f8f9fa;
  border-color: #f8f9fa;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-light social-media-button fa fa-facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/infinitygroupint/">Button</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-light social-media-button fa fa-instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/infinitygroup.ph/">Button</a>
      <li>
  </ul>
</div>
```